# Powershell AzureAD Script to change Groups from Static to Dynamic

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Trying to change some Azure AD Groups from Static to Dynamic via powershell (there are 75 groups so we need to do this somwhow)

originally i was trying to run it automatized from a list in TXT with this script:

```
$grouplist = Get-Content -Path "C:\foldername\filename.txt"

Set-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName $group -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -membershipRule "(user.department -eq "$group") and (user.jobTitle -eq "JobtitleXX")"

$counter += 1

if($counter -eq 1){​​​​​​
    Sleep -Seconds (60 * 1)
    $counter = 0
}​​​​​​

}​​​​​​
```

It fails.

So i tried it as a simple-single group script:

```
Set-AzureADMSGroup -Id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule '(user.department -eq "DepartmentXX") and (user.jobTitle -eq "JobTitleXX")' -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

But it is failing with this error:

```
Set-AzureADMSGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MembershipRule'.
At line:1 char:93
+ ... -102d855d224c -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule '(user. ...
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureADMSGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphV10.PowerShell.SetMSGroup
```

---

After a few tries nothing seems to work. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the `-MembershipRule` parameter on `Set-AzureADMSGroup` is still only available in the preview release of the `AzureAD` module.

```
# Install the preview module. May need to -AllowClobber
Install-Module AzureADPreview

# Import it into scripts instead of AzureAD. May need to -Force if AzureAD is loaded
Import-Module AzureADPreview

Get-Command Set-AzureADMSGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Parameters

Key                                                                 
---
GroupTypes
MembershipRule  # voila!
MembershipRuleProcessingState
```

As of the current version of [AzureAD](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/): `2.0.2.130`